# What does an outlined folder with a red X mean in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I pulled down a shared solution from GitHub;

[image: see image here]

However, I am unable to open one of the solution folders.

Answer (score 5):

Thought I would add, there is a bug where this icon appears when it shouldn't, it's probably caused by switching branches. Restarting Visual Studio seems to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This folder isn't in source control (in this case: Git because of GitHub)

[Git only tracks files and so not empty folders.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-a-blank-directory-to-a-git-repository)

The folder is probably mentioned in the .csproj